# workflows & approval | can we use formula field to field update in new creating the field update, without triggers

Tags: administration, workflow

IN workflows can we make formulas field to be **field to update** in "Immediate Workflow Actions"

Answer (score 2):

Formula fields are not writable.
Those are auto-calculate fields.

```
Formula     Allows users to automatically calculate values based on other values or fields such as merge fields.
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't update a formula field via workflow. It is updated based on changes to the fields that drive the formula.
What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm try to update the field "total amount" with total amount + tax to the total amount. Where tax is formula field and the value in detail page is not updating.

Comment: What if you created another formula field "Grand Total" that summed them together?

Answer (score 0):

Use newly supported functions to compare and return values in the Process Builder.
These new functions are now available to use in formulas.
INCLUDES
ISCHANGED
ISNEW
ISPICKVAL
PRIORVALUE
For example, check whether a case’s contact changed by using ISCHANGED([Case].ContactId). If this formula evaluates to true, your process executes the associated actions.

Note
Picklist fields are no longer evaluated as text fields in formulas. If your process uses a formula to reference a picklist field (for example, [Account].Industry = 'Agriculture'), we recommend changing the formula to use TEXT or ISPICKVAL instead (for example, ISPICKVAL([Account].Industry) = 'Agriculture').